# Python writes 0 to the file

Tags: python, windows, file, text, io

```
import os


fileHandle = open('booksNames.txt', 'r+')

def getData():
    data = os.system('dir /b /a /s *.pdf *.epub *.mobi')
    fileHandle.writelines(str(data))

fileHandle.close()
```

I'm trying to write the data returned by the os.system function to a file. But the only thing that gets written in file is 0. Here are some other variations that I tried as well.

```
import os

fileHandle = open('booksNames.txt', 'r+')

getData = lambda:os.system('dir /b /a /s *.pdf *.epub *.mobi')
data = getData()

fileHandle.writelines(str(data))
fileHandle.close()
```

On the output window, it gives perfect output but while writing to a text fileit writes zero. I've also tried using return but no use. Please Help.

Comment: The first variation contains two errors at least: 1) 'r+' is incorrect; 'r' for read(only) and 'w' for write (which is what you want).  2) the function GetData is never called.

Comment: @SurestTexas `'r+'` is read/write starting at the beginning of the file and so is fine

Comment: `os.system` does not return the output printed by the command line executed. It returns the process's exit status, which is 0.

Comment: @user2357112, that should be an answer when you add the correct call

Comment: @SurestTexas: `r+` is opening for read/write.

Comment: @SurestTexas indeed but his file is open for reading **and** writing

Comment: interesting.. did not know you could do that :)

Comment: I still think "Explicit is better than implicit".  I don't get why the OP wants to open the same file in read and write modes. It appears they want the output of the command written to a file... why not just make the command output its results to the text file directly?

Comment: what OS is this? Windows, or a Unix..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows (I assume you are using Windows since you are using the 'dir' command, not the Unix/Linux 'ls'):

simply let the command do the work.

```
os.system('dir /b /a /s *.pdf *.epub *.mobi >> booksNames.txt')
```

Using '>>' will append to any existing file.  just use '>' to write a new file.

I liked the other solution using subprocess, but since this is OS-specific anyway, I think this is simpler.

Comment: `with` is a better way to manage closing the file, but it doesn't do anything about the `0` thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.  There are a number of methods, but the simplest is:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> with open('out.txt','w') as f:
...     subprocess.call(['dir','/b','/a','/s','*.pdf','*.epub','*.mobi'],stdout=f,stderr=f,shell=True)
...
0
```

Zero is the exit code, but the content will be in `out.txt`.

Comment: The file system encoding is UTF-16LE, but this has cmd.exe encode the `dir` output using either the console's current output codepage (defaults to OEM) or ANSI if there's no console attached. That's ok if all of the filenames can be encoded in the OEM or ANSI codepages. But otherwise you'll have to remove `shell=True`; execute `'cmd.exe /u /c "{}"'.format(cmdline)`; and decode the output as UTF-16LE.

Comment: Also, in general you shouldn't use a list with `shell=True`. `subprocess.list2cmdline` isn't written for the cmd shell; it's written for MSVC `argv` parsing.